# VBS script error - "Expected Statement" - checked for errors

Tags: vbscript

I'm new so please forgive me if I'm wrong. I'm using this code here where I am getting a

> Expected Statement - Line 3 Char 1

Code:

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dowscript.sleep100wshShell.sendkeys
"{CAPSLOCK}"wshshell.sendkeys
"{NUMLOCK}"wshshell.sendkeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
loop
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: When trying to put that code within an existing loop like below I get invalid charecter line 1 char 1

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7" )
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
if colCDROMs.Count >= 1 then
do
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next ' cdrom
For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject
Next ' cdrom
loop
End If
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
  wshShell.Sendkeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
  wshshell.Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}"
  wshshell.Sendkeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
```

Comment: This maybe `dowscript.sleep100wshShell.sendkeys` it’s complete nonsense. Looks like spaces and line breaks are missing from the code, it might make more sense then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you copied this from, but it's lost spaces and line breaks, which is why you get the error

> Expected Statement - Line 3 Char 1

when executing it. The code should read;

```vb
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
  wshShell.Sendkeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
  wshshell.Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}"
  wshshell.Sendkeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
Loop
```

It's a fairly basic script that loops forever with a 100 millisecond wait *(to stop the machine from completely freezing as the OS battles with the script)* and sends the key sequence CAPSLOCK, NUMLOCK and SCROLLLOCK. To me, it just looks like a prank script designed to flash the LED key indicators on most standard QWERTY keyboards in sequence, over and over.

It's worth noting VBScripts in general are not designed to run forever and writing infinite loops like this one can have varying results.